# Recovery options on Lenovo with combo C: drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

I have a Lenovo Y570 with Windows 7.  It recently crashed.  It booted into the windows recovery screen.  I let it go ahead and try to repair the filesystem and now the system does not boot (says no media and then falls back to PXE attempt).

I booted it from a recovery USB and only then remembered that this thing has some sort of combined C: drive that uses both a SATA and a SSD drive.  When I boot the recovery system, I can see both drives, but neither show an NTFS partition.  I'm not sure if I should expect to on the SATA or not.

The SATA drive has a couple of smaller recovery partitions on it, but the large partition doesn't show as any filesystem.  Simple drive tests succeed, so it doesn't seem like the disk has physically crashed, just that the filesystem has corrupted.

My goal is to be able to view the filesystem and pull files off if possible, but I'm nervous about trying anything without understanding how the spinning disk and the SSD worked together.  Any suggestions for how I can attack this?

Comment: You have corrupt file systems that may or may not be recoverable. It has nothing to do with HDD and SSD though.

Comment: I'm asking because I've never worked on one of these "merged" Lenovo setups.  I don't know if the SSD is only used as a cache (in which case I can assume 100% of the filesystem should be present on the SATA as a normal NTFS), or if critical portions are on both.

Comment: That you downgraded the original OS to XP and are still using it in 2018 tells a story, a very sad one. Irrespective of the "setup" - BTW, even newer Y570 series laptops usually don't come with SSD - you may or may not be able to recover files using any of the available tools including the ones from a desktop Linux live session (booting from USB or DVD). Once done install a **supported** OS.

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I thought it was XP, but owner confirms it was Win 7.  I'll fix that in the question.  It's 100% stock, no OS was ever installed after purchase.

Comment: You can make and boot from a Windows 7 installation media and try a repair. Or use any other third-party tool as already mentioned. You're focusing too much on the supposed SSD when it doesn't matter. If it had a data partition the above applies as well; if not and being used as cache, for the purpose of recovering files, it can be ignored.